I am getting 405 error when I connect to MySQL server with Node.js, or any others like flask python or PHP
I want to make a basic login system for my hobby project, this project is mostly about database creation and front-end developement but I stuck with the back-end front-end connection. I can't seem to make admin login work..
project_files 
server side:
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Add this line to parse incoming request body

const app = express();

// Middleware to parse incoming request body as JSON
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Establish MySQL connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'hospital'
});

// Connect to MySQL
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to MySQL: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to MySQL as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

// Endpoint to handle login
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.query;

    // Query the database to check the credentials
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?', [username, password], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error querying the database:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while processing your request.' });
            return;
        }

        if (results.length > 0) {
            // Username and password match
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
        } else {
            // Username or password is incorrect
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid username or password' });
        }
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

client side:
// static/scripts/client_admin.js

const usernameInput = document.getElementById("username");
const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
const showPasswordButton = document.getElementById("showPassword");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
const messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");

showPasswordButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (passwordInput.type === "password") {
        passwordInput.type = "text";
        showPasswordButton.textContent = "Hide Password";
    } else {
        passwordInput.type = "password";
        showPasswordButton.textContent = "Show Password";
    }
});

loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const username = usernameInput.value;
    const password = passwordInput.value;

    // Send a POST request to the server with the username and password
    fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            messageDiv.textContent = "Login successful";
        } else {
            messageDiv.textContent = "Invalid username or password";
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle any network errors
        console.error('Error:', error);
        messageDiv.textContent = "An error occurred while processing your request.";
    });
});

console.log(window.location.port);     // Print the port



admin page:
<!-- static/index_admin_login.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Admin Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background_container"></div>
        <div class="title_container">
            <h1>Patient Tracking and Management System</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="login_container">
            <a href="index.html" target="_self">
                <button>Back to main page</button>
            </a>
            <h2>Admin Login Panel</h2>

            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input name="username" id="username" type="text" style="height: 20px; width: 100px">
            <div></div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" style="height: 20px; width: 100px">
            <div></div>
            <button id="login" type="submit" style="position: sticky">Login</button>

            <div></div>

            <button id="showPassword">Show Password</button>
            <div id="message"></div>

        </div>

        <script src="scripts/client_admin.js"></script> <!-- including the client_admin.js file -->

    </body>
</html>

database:
CREATE DATABASE Hospital;
-- QUERIED 1

USE Hospital;
CREATE TABLE Patients (
    PatientID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Surname VARCHAR(50),
    DateOfBirth DATE,
    Gender VARCHAR(10),
    TelephoneNumber VARCHAR(20),
    Adress VARCHAR(255),
    EmailAdress VARCHAR(255),
    Password VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Doctors (
    DoctorID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Surname VARCHAR(50),
    AreaOfExpertise VARCHAR(100),
    DoctorsHospital VARCHAR(100),
    EmailAdress VARCHAR(255),
    Password VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Admin (
    AdminID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Username VARCHAR(255),
    EmailAdress VARCHAR(255),
    Password VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Appointments (
    AppointmentID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    PatientID INT,
    DoctorID INT,
    AppointmentDate DATE,
    AppointmentTime TIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES Patients(PatientID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DoctorID) REFERENCES Doctors(DoctorID)
);
CREATE TABLE Reports (
    ReportID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ReportDate DATE,
    ReportContent TEXT,
    FileURL VARCHAR(255),
    FileType VARCHAR(50),
    PatientID INT,
    DoctorID INT,
    AdminID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES Patients(PatientID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DoctorID) REFERENCES Doctors(DoctorID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AdminID) REFERENCES Admin(AdminID)
);
-- QUERIED 2

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
-- QUERIED 3 (for enabling the node.js to work with mysql)

INSERT INTO Admin (Username, EmailAdress, Password) VALUES ("admin", "admin@gmail.com", "0123");
-- QUERIED 4

SELECT * FROM Patients;
SELECT * FROM Doctors;
SELECT * FROM Admin;

and the error i get from the console when i use  Live Server vs-code extension to view my html files from firefox: 
error
I tried to install an extension to block CORS but still getting the error..
ext

You call your login function as POST
fetch('/login', {
    method: 'POST',

but you have defined it as a GET method
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {

this could not work. Change the .get in the backend to .post and you should be a step ahead

I fix that but still getting the same error, probably CORS blocking it caused by the browser..

If so you should see it in the browsers developer console. did you only change the source or did you also restart the backend?

I restart server.js everytime I change any code, from back or front, no matter what. I should supposed to do that right?
